# Why ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ")": syntax error: INSERT INTO "user_friendships" () VALUES ()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

Why Why ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ")": syntax error: INSERT INTO "user_friendships" () VALUES ()

When trying to test:

$ ruby -I test test/unit/user_friendships_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFriendshipsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
should belong_to (:user)
should belong_to (:friend)

test "that creating a frinedship works without raising an exception" do

    assert_nothing_raised do
        UserFriendship.create user: users(:a), friend: friends(:b)
    end

end

end
```

Any idea?

UPDATE: his is part of the Schema.rb

```
create_table "user_friendships", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.integer  "friend_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

add_index "user_friendships", ["user_id", "friend_id"], :name => "index_user_friendships_on_user_id_and_friend_id"

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "first_name"
 t.string   "last_name"
 t.string   "profile_name"
 t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0,  :null => false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Comment: Do you have any columns in that table?

Comment: Can you post the code for UserFriendship and also your db schema?

Comment: Yes, I do have columns in that table. I just updated the post with part of the Schema

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well. It seems to be related to screwing up the rails naming conventions. In my case, doing "rails g model activity_item" instead of "rails g model activity_items" solved the issue.