# Rails 4 SQLiteException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am running into SQLiteException that seems to be causing problem.

Schema.rb

```
create_table "features", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name_key"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "features", ["name_key"], name: "index_features_on_name_key"

create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "code"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "organizations_features", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "organization_id"
  t.integer "feature_id"
end
```

This is current schema and i explicity created table organizations_features(still through migration but a separate migration that references a join table) as otherwise create_join_table would create "features_organizations". In that process, if i run

> rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load

I still keep getting the following error even without loading a single record in any tables(i never ran db:seed).

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ")": syntax error: INSERT INTO "organizations_features" () VALUES ()
```

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590720/why-activerecordstatementinvalid-sqlite3sqlexception-near-syntax-erro) seem to suggest to make the join table name all singular as in organization_feature, but since we share the schema with other services, it is imperative that we use the same naming conventions.

Note: even i tried to create table using migration "create_join_table" the problem seem to persist"

Update : seeds.rb

```
organization = Organization.create!(name: 'XYZ', code: 'xyz')
feature = Feature.create!(name_key: 'Some Feature')
user = User.create!(name:  "user1",
                     email: "user@abcd.org",
                     password:              "password123",
                     password_confirmation: "password123",
                     profile_id: profile.id)
OrganizationsFeature.create!(feature_id: feature.id, organization_id:  organization.id)
```

where OrganizationsFeature looks like this

```
class OrganizationsFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

Comment: Post the content of the `seed.rb` file.

Comment: updated with seed file.

Comment: So, I found the solution incase if some one else runs into the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to the question in case if someone else runs into the same issue. The test/fixtures/organizations_features.yml file has null records

```
one :{}  
two: {}
```

which was causing null records to be inserted into the table. This data is loaded every time and hence insert error.
Having proper data/deleting the file solved the issue.